# How can I change the language of runtime errors at Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, runtime-error

According to Microsoft documentation the reason I see it at a different language (which is not English) is because of my OS language.

Where can I set it to be in English (and not as my OS language is)?

Thanks,

Comment: _Which_ runtime errors?

Comment: All run time errors (appears in hebrew)

Comment: Which runtime? Do you mean runtime errors from your compiled code? I don't think there is any way to change those from OS default language.

Comment: In particular, those errors have nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: Messages when I have an Exception during runtime

Comment: I suspect you mean .Net.  Again, that has nothing to do with VS; VS simply displays the exception message from your code or from .Net itself.

Comment: I understand. So is there any way that you know to change it if possible at all?

Comment: If you want English exception messages then simply change the default Windows language.  Ask at superuser.com if you don't know how to do that, don't forget to mention the Windows version.  You could also ask how to remove the .NET framework language pack, not so sure how feasible that is.